# Why does my Red Kuri squach have few female slowers and those it does have don't bloom but fall off?

Tags: squash

I have 2 Red Kuri squash that have a lot of male blooms but very few female.  Those females that are showing up don't bloom (so I can't pollinate) and ultimately fall off without developing.  I am in zone 5.  The plants look very healthy with no evidence of pests or disease.  They are in the same raised bed as a transplanted zuchini squash which is also not showing female flowers.